# O que significa a expressão “cair de Madura”?

Tags: significado

Exemplos:

> Uma laranja cai de madura num quintal português.
>
> Esta maioria política vai cair de madura. [[Correio da Manhã]](http://www.cmjornal.xl.pt/opiniao/detalhe/esta-maioria-politica-vai-cair-de-madura.html) e [[Nicole cai de madura]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyWoGPEascE)

Comment: Olá user948, bem-vindo ao melhor site de língua portuguesa em todo o mundo e arredores. No segundo exemplo, *cair de madura* é usado em sentido figurado; se puderes dar mais contexto, será mais fácil interpretar, e obterás uma resposta melhor. Imagino que tenhas tirado essas frases de algum lado. Não queres indicar a fonte?

Comment: Olá Jacinto, obrigado pela resposta! O contexto do primeiro exemplo: é o que está escrito debaixo duma imagem em que uma laranja está a cair (talvez "de madura" signifique "por ser madura"?).
A segunda frase é desta página: http://www.cmjornal.xl.pt/opiniao/detalhe/esta-maioria-politica-vai-cair-de-madura.html 

 e ainda encontrei um vídeo em que uma rapariga dança e depois cai cujo título é "Nicole cai de madura" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyWoGPEascE

Comment: Será que não caberia a ideia de despencar?

Comment: User948, ainda acerca da outra pergunta: vê *autuar* no dicionário, e se a relação com *multar* ou a situação no vídeo continuar a suscitar dúvidas, isso aí já seria objeto para uma pergunta válida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tenho a certeza mas segundo a explicação dada no [Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/cair+de+maduro/) penso que nesse contexto poderá querer dizer "cair por si própria" no sentido de "não se vai aguentar", possivelmente para significar figurativamente que não vai durar ou vai ter um fim prematuro por estar "condenado à partida".

Poderá alternativamente querer dizer "cair de velho" ou "apodrecer".

Comment: fixe, obrigado!

Comment: É exatamente isso.

Answer (score 3):

Atentando ao exemplo, e usando a expansão de significado, podemos entender que "cair de maduro" significa "ficar  inadequado", "passar de seu tempo", "perder a relevância em vista de acontecimentos/fatos/características recentes/novas subjacentes a algo". Enfim, é algo que tende a ruim, e que deve ser substituído porque inadequado, antiquado.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, nesse contexto aí da segunda frase, eu não faço ideia do que quer dizer, mas aqui no Brasil eu lembro que quando eu era pequeno se dizia "caiu de maduro" só de brincadeira quando alguém levava um tombo digno de risada, que nem no vídeo que você mostrou aí do "Nicole cai de madura".